# How to email editors of a Google Sheet using App Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, google-apps-script-editor

I am trying to write a function that emails the editors of a Google sheet based on the value of a cell. I am running into issues with making this happen and would love some pointers. For some context- the sheet is a back end of a form and we are asking if the person filling out the form needs any special accommodations prior to our event.

I was able to successfully set up a function that emails the owner. The problem is that the "owner" aka the one creating the forms, will JUST be making the forms and not running the event themselves.

They are adding the people managing the event as editors. So I want the script to email the editors when an attendee needs special accommodations.

This is what I have for emailing the owner:

```js
function accommodateNotify() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var ownerEmail = ss.getOwner().getEmail();
  var startingRow = 6;
  Logger.log(ownerEmail);
  var name = ss.getName();
  Logger.log(name);
  var url = ss.getUrl();
  Logger.log(url);
    
  var lastRow = getLastNonEmptyRow(sheet.getRange(1, 83, sheet.getLastRow(), 1));
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  var needsAccommodation = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 83).getValue();
  Logger.log(needsAccommodation);
  var requiredAccommodation = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 85).getValue();
     
  if (needsAccommodation == "Yes") {
    var message = "An attendee for " + name + " " + " has stated they need accommodations. Please review: " +url;
    var subject = "Accommodation Request Alert";
    Logger.log("sending email...\n" + "  subject: " + subject + "\n  message: " + message);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(ownerEmail, subject, message);
  }
}
```

The problem with using the `getEditors` is that it returns an array (due to their possibly being more than one editor). Do you have any guidance on how I would structure this for it to email the editors?

I managed to put this together, but it's emailing the editors twice for some reason...

```js
function accommodateNotify() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var editors = ss.getEditors();
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(editors[i].getEmail());
    //var ownerEmail = ss.getOwner().getEmail();
    var startingRow = 2;
    var name = ss.getName();
    Logger.log(name);
    var url = ss.getUrl();
    Logger.log(url);
    var lastRow = getLastNonEmptyRow(sheet.getRange(1, 29, sheet.getLastRow(), 1));
    Logger.log(lastRow);
    var needsAccommodation = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 29).getValue();
    Logger.log(needsAccommodation);
    var requiredAccommodation = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 85).getValue();

    if (needsAccommodation == "Yes") {
      var message = "A student for " + name + " " + " has stated they need accommodations. Please review: " +url;
      var subject = "Accommodation Request Alert";
      Logger.log("sending email...\n" + "  subject: " + subject + "\n  message: " + message);
      GmailApp.sendEmail(editors, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: double check where your `for` loop ends.  If you are including `GmailApp.sendEmail(editors, ...)` in your loop, then that would be your reason why it is going twice.  Either pull GmailApp.send out of the for loop, or just send `editors[i]` an email on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question your problem is that you want to send an email to the editors being `editors` an array containing all the editors. Also, noting that [GmailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) can only send emails to a single recipient at a time.

Below I have propossed a change in your script iterating over all the editors to then be able to send an email to each one of them. The code has self-explanatory comments.

Also note that [getEditors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geteditors) returns an User object, not the emails and therefore these must be obtained using [getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user.html#getemail).

```js
if (needsAccommodation == "Yes") {
      var message = "A student for " + name + " " + " has stated they need accommodations. Please review: " +url;
      var subject = "Accommodation Request Alert";
      Logger.log("sending email...\n" + "  subject: " + subject + "\n  message: " + message);
      
      // iterate over all the editors that are in the array
      for(i=0;i<editors.length;i++){
      // send an email with the same message and subject to each of the editors
      GmailApp.sendEmail(editors[i].getEmail(), subject, message);
      }
    }
```